# How to put even space between divs using flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is the kind of placement I would like to achieve with `display:flex`. I want the `text1` to appear at the top, `text3` at the bottom and `text2` in the middle.

[image]

However the end result I got is this:

[image]

I am expecting `align-self` to be able to pull the top and the bottom `div` toward each end.

What did I miss?

Here is [my html mark-up and css stylesheet](http://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/zrNxxW)

**HTML:**

```
<div class=container>

  <div class='logo-container hidden-xs'>
    <span>LOGO on the side</span>
  </div>
  <div class='text-container' > 
    <div class='visible-xs'>
      <span>LOGO</span>
    </div>
    <div class=text1>
      Text1
    </div>
    <div class=text2>
      Text 2
    </div>
    <div class=text3>
      Text 3
    </div>
  </div>  

</div>
```

**css:**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row;  no effect */
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 300px;
}

.container span {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
}

.text-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

.do-i-need-this {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
} 

.text1 {
  align-self: flex-start;  
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;

}

.text2 {

  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;

}


.text3 {
  align-self: flex-end;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these to your `text-container` class

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

You can get rid of `align-self`

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @EdDogan is correct. My answer expands on his solution with an explanation.

The primary obstacle you're facing to achieving your layout is the lack of a flex container for the text elements. In other words, `.text-container` must have `display: flex` applied in order for flex properties to work on child elements.

Then, to align the flex items on opposite edges, with one in the middle, use `justify-content: space-between`, which is perfect for this requirement (and works along the vertical axis because `flex-direction` is `column`).

```
.text-container {
    display: flex; /* new */
    justify-content: space-between; /* new */
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVabqm)

*Few more notes:*

- If the middle item simply needs to exist between the other two, then `justify-content: space-between` (or `space-around`) works fine.

  If, however, the middle item needs to be *centered* in the container, then the `justify-content` method works only when all items are the same height. If any of the items have a different height  (or width, in `flex-direction: row`), this will cause an imbalance, and centering will be off.

  For more details, a demo and a workaround, see Box #76 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276
- With regard to:

  ```
  .container {   /* flex-direction: row;  no effect */ }
  ```

  When you establish a flex container (by applying `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to an element), several default rules go into effect. One of these rules is `flex-direction: row`. Hence, your own declaration of this rule is redundant and will have no effect.
- With regard to:

  ```
  .text1 { align-self: flex-start; }

  .text3 { align-self: flex-end; }
  ```

  The first reason this doesn't work is because the parent of these elements is not a flex container. `.text-container` doesn't have `display: flex` applied, so any flex properties on the child elements are ignored.

  The second reason it doesn't work is because, even with `display: flex` applied, you are in `flex-direction: column`. This means that the cross-axis is horizontal, and the `align-` properties control flex items left/right, not up/down.